How to get rid of warning in console when using enqueueSnackbar in react/nextjs
Do you have any suggesstion how to solve the below warning message in console?
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <html>.

please help, thanks in advance.
have no idea what to do
